# React component not re-rendering on URL parameter change when using useEffect hook to fetch data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, use-effect

Here's the issue:

I have a component that is meant to be the same structure for `≈ 25` different items/pages. So, I do what anyone would when trying to use React, and I am passing dynamic URL parameters into my API request (pictured below).

```
const [{ items, isLoading, isError }] = useDataApi(
`http://localhost:5000/api/teams/topspending/${params.team}`,
[],
params.team);
```

This is simply using a `useEffect` component that has been separated for simplicity (pictured below).

```
const useDataApi = (initialUrl, initialData, effect) => {
  console.log("start/top Data API");
  const [items, setItems] = useState(initialData);
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(initialUrl);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {

    setUrl(initialUrl);

    const abortCtrl = new AbortController();
    const opts = { signal: abortCtrl.signal };

    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsError(false);
      setIsLoading(true);
      console.log("data loading");

      try {
        console.log(url, "this should be the new Url");
        const result = await axios(url, opts);

        setItems(result.data.data);
      } catch (error) {
        setIsError(true);
      }
      console.log("data loaded...");
      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    fetchData();
    return () => abortCtrl.abort();
  }, [effect]);

  return [{ items, isLoading, isError }];
};

export default useDataApi;
```

The task is pretty simple. Upon clicking on a simple navigation link in the navbar to change the URL from `http://localhost:5000/api/teams/topspending/Team1` to `http://localhost:5000/api/teams/topspending/Team2` I am wishing that the SAME component will re-render after fetching NEW data with the UPDATED URL.

I have tried many things... and I can get the component to update after every URL change, BUT the data fetched is still the OLD data!

(I am using React-Router to route the single component to this link)

Comment: The `useDataApi` hook is incomplete could you add in the arguments that it takes i.e. the top part of the function is missing.

Comment: Is the new data from the dynamic URL is correct? If so, you can new data, update the state and the component does not re render? Also the URL state is not needed just use it for the axios without setting the state again for no reason

Comment: @yudhiesh Sorry, I just updated the code snippet to show the parameters of the `useDataApi`. It has 3 parameters that I pass in for state, errors, useEffect refresh.

Comment: @MichaelParkadze Thanks for the response, I just updated a few parameters that were missing from the `useDataApi` in the code snippet above. The new data from the url is correct, but the `useEffect` hook doesn't see that until I use `setUrl` inside the function. BUT, for whatever reason, no matter where inside the function i put the `setUrl`, the `useEffect` only updates the url AFTER it has already started the data fetch again (with the old url). If i don't add the `setUrl` inside the `useEffect`, I can't seem to get the `useEffect` to pick up on the change. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think there are 2 little issues in your code.

**Inside the parent function**

This is my main function that is going to use your custom hook. If you see, I don't use interpolation because it is not going to be detected by your custom hook. That is why your `initialUrl` variable (Your URL) in your custom hook never change.

```
const App = () => {
  const [id, setId] = React.useState(1);
  const response = useDataApi(
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + id,
    [],
    id,
  );

  return (
    <>
      <div>My id {id}</div>
      <button onClick={() => setId(id + 1)}>Click Me!</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

**Inside the custom hook**

It seems to me that you are misunderstanding the **setState** function provided by react.
Remember that every time you call the **setState** function is not synchronous. I mean, if you use `setUrl(initialUrl)`, then in the next line of code your state variable `url` will not necessarily have the values already updated. To know more about it, you can read this: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#when-is-setstate-asynchronous

I would suggest using another variable to call the correct URL and change the variable names of your custom hook. I added some comments to your code `//Note:`

```
export const useDataApi = (initialUrl, initialData, effect) => {
  console.log("start/top Data API", effect, initialUrl);
  const [items, setItems] = useState(initialData);
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(initialUrl);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Note: This not sync function
    setUrl(initialUrl);

    const abortCtrl = new AbortController();
    const opts = { signal: abortCtrl.signal };

    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsError(false);
      setIsLoading(true);
      console.log("data loading");

      try {
        console.log(url, "this should be the new Url");
        // Note: I changed this url variable of your state, to use your initialUrl variable. (this initialUrl parameter should have your UPDATED URL)
        const result = await axios(initialUrl, opts);

        setItems(result.data);
      } catch (error) {
        setIsError(true);
      }
      console.log("data loaded...");
      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    fetchData();
    return () => abortCtrl.abort();
  }, [effect]);

  return [{ items, isLoading, isError }];
};
```

I Hope, this can help you!.

Comment: I see! I am still a bit behind on fully grasping `useState`... I thought I knew, but clearly not! I ended up just taking out the `setUrl` inside of the `useEffect` as it was useless I believe? Just to be clear, you recommend me keeping the url `useState` and simply changing the name from `initialUrl` to something more practical correct? Thanks so much again! I hope that I at least structured it correctly! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

setState is asynchronous, so there's no guarantee as to when it will be affected before the next render. There's multiple ways to rewrite your code to work more predictably, but with the examples you've provided the easiest solution is to remove the url state altogether and just use `initalUrl` in your call to `axios`.

This isn't great.

So another option would be to keep your `url` state and add a second `useEffect` that watches `url`.

eg.

```
const useDataApi = (initialUrl, initialData, effect) => {
  console.log("start/top Data API");
  const [items, setItems] = useState(initialData);
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(initialUrl);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setUrl(initialUrl);
  }, [effect]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const abortCtrl = new AbortController();
    const opts = { signal: abortCtrl.signal };

    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsError(false);
      setIsLoading(true);
      console.log("data loading");

      try {
        console.log(url, "this should be the new Url");
        const result = await axios(url, opts);

        setItems(result.data.data);
      } catch (error) {
        setIsError(true);
      }
      console.log("data loaded...");
      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    fetchData();
    return () => abortCtrl.abort();

  }, [url])

  return [{ items, isLoading, isError }];
};

export default useDataApi;
```

Still not great, but does what you're trying to do?

Comment: This did work! Previously, I tried to use another `useEffect` in my main component, but I could not get that to work for many reasons. I see how it works, but I guess I don't know why? I am still pretty new to React, but just unsure why it wouldn't catch the NEW initialUrl when it changed? Also, if I put a setUrl inside of the original `useEffect` it also would not pick up on it, not sure why tho? 

This is great! I really appreciate it! But you said there was a better way to write the code overall? suggestions? I want to duplicated this process many times probably!

Comment: it looks like you want to use the `effect` parameter as the trigger for calling the api, but you're also relying on the `url` being able to change, which likely should also trigger the api call? If so then my first suggestion is better, and you should change your initial code to remove the state hook for `url`, and have your single effect watch both `effect` and `url`. Further, It also might be better to kill off the `effect` parameter altogether and just watch for a change in url?

Comment: Understood! That makes total sense now! Thank you for your help! It really means a lot!